# Why can’t i use a supermesh analysis on this circuit?

Tags: homework, mesh-analysis

Hi I want to ask you why i can't use a supermesh like this blue line.
The answer of this question is io=3.1 A.
I tried several times to use a supermesh but It doesn't work. 
Is it because of the dependent current source?
Please tell me the reason....

[image]

Comment: Sorry, we won't do your homework for you. Show us all of your equations and explain your thought process.

Comment: Can you show us your equations?

Comment: And the supermesh should not contain any current source in his path.

Comment: I think that a current source that is only in **a single mesh** can be part of the supermesh. It gives you an equation for the supermesh current by inspection.

Answer (score 2):

Just re-draw the schematic (note that I chose a specific node for "ground" as the (-) terminal of the \$+12\:\text{V}\$ voltage source.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftrJ2Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The whole thing is a lot less complicated, now.

To see how I started to produce the above schematic, see my modifications to your schematic below:

[image]

You can use KCL to compute \$V_\text{X}\$ as (currents flowing out of the node on the left side of equals, currents flowing into the node on the right side of equals):

$$\frac{V_\text{X}}{R_1}+I_1 + 5\:\Omega^{-1}\left(12\:\text{V}-V_\text{X}\right)=\frac{12\:\text{V}}{R_1}$$

Solve that for \$V_\text{X}\$.

Now use KCL to compute \$V_\text{Y}\$ as (currents flowing out of the node on the left, currents flowing into the node on the right):

$$\frac{V_\text{Y}}{R_2}+\frac{V_\text{Y}}{R_2}=\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_2}+\frac{12\:\text{V}}{R_3}+5\:\Omega^{-1}\left(12\:\text{V}-V_\text{X}\right)$$

Solve that for \$V_\text{Y}\$.

Now simply compute \$I_0=\frac{12\:\text{V}-V_\text{Y}}{R_3}\$.

You will find the same answer as you gave.